# Error al recuperar el ultimo ID de un registro y utilizarla - codeigniter - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hol  tengo problemas  con mi codigo **PHP**, la cabecera si **REGISTRA** eso quiere decir que todo esta bien pero cuando queiro recuperar el ID me sale el error no se si el **error** esta en mi controlador a la hora de llamar ese **id** o en mi **modelo** a la hora de consultar sobre el ultimo **ID**.

**Controlador :**

```
   public function guardar_venta() {

        $id_cliente = $this->input->post('id_cliente');
        $descuento = $this->input->post('descuento');
        $efectivo = $this->input->post('efectivo');
        $vuelto = $this->input->post('vuelto');
        $total = $this->input->post('total');
        $detalle = $this->input->post('detalle');

        $this->venta->guardar_cabecera($id_cliente, $descuento, $efectivo, $vuelto, $total);

        $id_cabecera = $this->input->post('id_venta');

        if (isset($id_cabecera)) {

            if ($detalle != "[") {
                $array_detalle = json_decode($detalle);
                foreach ($array_detalle as $objeto) {
                    $id_producto = $objeto->id_producto;
                    $cantidad = $objeto->cantidad;
                    $precio = $objeto->precio;
                    $subtotal = $objeto->subtotal;

                    $this->venta->guardar_detalle($id_cabecera, $id_producto, $cantidad, $precio, $subtotal);
                }
            }
            echo 1;
        }
    }
```

**Modelo :**

```
   public function guardar_cabecera($id_cliente, $descuento, $efectivo, $vuelto, $total) {
        $this->db_caja->reconnect();
        $this->db_caja->query("INSERT INTO venta VALUES(null,'$id_cliente','$descuento','$efectivo','$vuelto','$total',NOW());");
        return $this->db_caja->insert_id();
    }

    public function guardar_detalle($id_cabecera, $id_producto, $cantidad, $precio, $subtotal) {
        $this->db_caja->reconnect();
        $query = $this->db_caja->query("INSERT INTO detalle_venta VALUES (null,'$id_cabecera','$id_producto','$cantidad','$precio','$subtotal');");
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCION A LA HORA DE LLAMARLO ESTABA INCORRECTO :**

Tenia que poner un identificador a la variable que me iba a recuperar,
y este mismo ya me traia el **ID**, en la linia siguiente solo era igualarlo y ya con eso solucione el problema.

**CONTROALDOR :**

```
public function guardar_venta() {

        $id_cliente = $this->input->post('id_cliente');
        $descuento = $this->input->post('descuento');
        $efectivo = $this->input->post('efectivo');
        $vuelto = $this->input->post('vuelto');
        $total = $this->input->post('total');
        $detalle = $this->input->post('detalle');

        $id_cabe = $this->venta->guardar_cabecera($id_cliente, $descuento, $efectivo, $vuelto, $total);

        $id_cabecera = $id_cabe;

        if (isset($id_cabecera)) {

            if ($detalle != "[") {
                $array_detalle = json_decode($detalle);
                foreach ($array_detalle as $objeto) {
                    $id_producto = $objeto->id_producto;
                    $cantidad = $objeto->cantidad;
                    $precio = $objeto->precio;
                    $subtotal = $objeto->subtotal;

                    $this->venta->guardar_detalle($id_cabecera, $id_producto, $cantidad, $precio, $subtotal);
                }
            }
            echo 1;
        }
    }
```